# Upload a file attachment for Salesforce in C#

Tags: c#, salesforce, soap-client

I've seen [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919715/upload-a-file-to-salesforce-using-connector) to build and send an attachment to Salesforce in Java, but how is this accomplished in C#?

Edit - I'm also using [this page](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/NET-Development/Attaching-a-file-to-salesforce-via-the-API/td-p/11588) as a reference, but I still don't know how to finish the last part where I try to create and save the attachment.

```
SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
LoginResult lr = client.login(new LoginScopeHeader(), username, password);

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(myFileLocation);
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(myFileLocation);
byte[] byteArray = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
stream.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.Body = byteArray;
attachment.Name = myFileName + ".txt";
attachment.IsPrivate = false;

SaveResult saveResult = client.create(new sObject[] { attachment })[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct in general. With the following changes.

After calling login, you will need to assign the resulting SessionId and ServerUrl to the client.

```
SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
LoginResult lr = client.login(new LoginScopeHeader(), username, password);
client.SessionHeaderValue = new SforceService.SessionHeader();
client.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = li.sessionId;
client.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
```

You should check the SaveResult to see if the record was created and what the new Id is.

```
//...
SaveResult saveResult = client.create(new sObject[] { attachment })[0];
if (saveResult .success){ 
    // saveResult.id contains id of newly created attachment
} else {
    //saveResult .errors[0] contains reason why attachment couldn't be created.
}
```

Comment: SoapClient doesn't have SessionHeaderValue or Url parameters, and SforceService is not an available object for me.  How do I get those objects to appear?  I'm using the Salesforce Enterprise wsdl.

Comment: I had to add the enterprise wsdl as a WEB REFERENCE, not just a Service Reference.  This is kind of difficult in VS2012, but it's working for the moment.  Thanks